# sqlbindparameter not used for all parameters - mysql & C++

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc

I have the following table defined in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO routemaster_log (`EntryDateTime`,`Entry`,`Message`,`EntryType`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
CREATE TABLE `routemaster_log` (
  `EntryDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Entry` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
  `Message` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `EntryType` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INFORMATION'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the following C++ code to write a record to it

```
void LogEntries::Insert(string_t LogText, string_t LogType, int MessageNumber)
{
    SQLHANDLE   hEnv;
    SQLRETURN   retCode;
    SQLCHAR*    query;
    SQLINTEGER textLength = SQL_NTS;

    // now set the text to be written to char *     
    char* logText = from_string_t(LogText);
    char* logType = from_string_t(LogType);

    std::string SQLQuery("INSERT INTO routemaster_log (`Entry`,`Message`,`EntryType`) VALUES (?,?,?)");

    query = (SQLCHAR *)SQLQuery.c_str();

.
.
.

    // log Text
    retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
        SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 0, 0,
        logText, sizeof(logText), &textLength);

    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (LogText)" << std::endl;
    }

    // Message Number
    retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &MessageNumber, 0, NULL);
    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (Message Number)" << std::endl;
    }

    // Log Type
    retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, 
        SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 0, 0, 
        logType, sizeof(logType), &textLength);

    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (LogType)" << std::endl;
    }

    retCode = SQLExecDirectA(hStmnt, query, SQL_NTS);
    if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLWCHAR Msg[255], SqlState[6];
        SQLINTEGER NativeError;
        SQLRETURN ret2;
        SQLSMALLINT i, MsgLen;

        i = 1;
        while ((ret2 = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmnt, i, SqlState, &NativeError,
            Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {

            std::cout << Msg << std::endl;

            i++;
        }
        std::cout << "SQL Insert failed writing data to database." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

everything is fine until the SQLExecDirectA this fails with the SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters error (retrieved in the following while loop).

I would expect this if the number of Parameters being bound was different to the number of '?' in the query but they are the same.

Anyone got a suggestion as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually two issues with the code in the question.

a) The Calls to *SQLBindParameter* go before the call to *SQLPrepareA*

b) In the Calls to SQLBindParameter the second Parameter gives the position of the parameter

The revised code - which works is as follows;

```
// log Text
retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT,
    SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 0, 0,
    logText, sizeof(logText), &textLength);

if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (LogText)" << std::endl;
}

// Message Number
retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &MsgNumber, 0, NULL);
if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (Message Number)" << std::endl;
}

// Log Type
retCode = SQLBindParameter(hStmnt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, 
    SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 0, 0, 
    logType, sizeof(logType), &textLength);

if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    std::cout << "SQL Insert failed binding parameters (LogType)" << std::endl;
}

retCode = SQLPrepareA(hStmnt, query, SQL_NTS);
if (retCode != SQL_SUCCESS && retCode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    std::cout << "SQL Insert failed preparing statement" << std::endl;
}


retCode = SQLExecDirectA(hStmnt, query, SQL_NTS);
```